# what is the correct way to pass 3 where () conditions in the same function, multiple filters | eloquente - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I would like to know if I am doing it right, if my code is semantic and safe.

I need to load a page from the database, but to do this I need to cross some data and all must be compatible, the verification takes place as follows:

url: mysite.com/company/page/code

- 1 - Check the first parameter to see if company exists or not.
- 2 - check the second parameter to find out if company X has that page or not
- 3 - Check the third parameter to find out if page Y has a code and if that code matches what you typed.
- 4 - If the user arrived here and all the data are correct, please load the page and the corresponding data.

Here he checks if user X has page Y, my doubt is if I can do it like this or is there another way.

```
   $page = Page::where('name', $name)->where('page_name', $page_name)->first();
            if ($page === null) {
                  return view('company.pages.erros.404', compact('name', page)); 
            }
```

Here is similar to the other, he checks if user X has page Y and if the code of page Y is correct, as in others, my doubt is if it is correct to put several WHERE clauses in the code

```
$pagecode = Page::where('name', $name)->where('page_name', $pagen_name)->where('code', $pcode)->first();
if ($pagecode === null) {
      return view('company.pages.erros.invalid_code', compact('company, name', page, pcode)); 
}
```

---

as I thought you would want the code in general context, here is the full function code

```
public function loadpage($name, $page_name, $pcode)
{
    $company = Company::where('name', $name)->first();
    if ($company === null) {
          return view('company.not_register', compact('name')); 
    }
    $page = Page::where('name', $name)->where('page_name', $page_name)->first();
    if ($page === null) {
          return view('company.pages.erros.404', compact('name', page)); 
    }

    $pagecode = Page::where('name', $name)->where('page_name', $page_name)->where('code', $pcode)->first();
    if ($pagecode === null) {
          return view('company.pages.erros.invalid_code', compact('company, name', page, pcode)); 
    }

    $personality = DB::table('personalities')->where('name', $name)->first();

     return view('company.pages.index', compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'page', pcode));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses), I came up with the following result:

```
public function loadpage($name, $page_name, $pcode)
{
    $company = Company::where('name', $name)->first();
    if ($company === null) {
          return view('company.not_register', compact('name')); 
    }
    $page = Page::where([ ['name', $name],
['page_name', $page_name],])->first();
    if ($page === null) {
          return view('company.pages.erros.404', compact('name', page)); 
    }

    $pagecode = Page::where([ ['name', $name],
['page_name', $page_name], ['code', $pcode],])->first();
    if ($pagecode === null) {
          return view('company.pages.erros.invalid_code', compact('company, name', page, pcode)); 
    }

    $personality = DB::table('personalities')->where('name', $name)->first();

     return view('company.pages.index', compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'page', pcode));
}
```

now it's up to colleagues more experienced than me to see if that's right or is it possible to improve / simplify

Comment: If you want someone to suggest improvements/alternate approaches, code review is the place to go: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also, you have a syntax error in this answer: `[page_name'` missing the opening `'` (in two places)

Comment: sorry, my mistake, but is it correct now?  because it's bureaucratic to open a question there, just to know if it's right or not, we're here now, it doesn't seem necessary :)

Comment: The syntax error is fixed, but I won't comment on the approach, as that's not the point of Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are searching in a single model and you are not sure when which fields occur you might want to use laravel's `when()` method. It will help you search the database only when the field is available for you. for an example:

```
$sortBy = null;

$users = DB::table('users')
                ->when($sortBy, function ($query, $sortBy) {
                    return $query->orderBy($sortBy);
                }, function ($query) {
                    return $query->orderBy('name');
                })
                ->get();
```

You will get the idea from here [conditional query in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses)

Comment: It could also be, however, as I use three checks here, I think it would get bigger and more complex than what I'm doing here, because I haven't even applied paginate () yet.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple where clause to pass to a where clause, you can have a array containing arrays with the structure as you would have in the where method, like:

```php
$where = [
    ['name', $name],
    ['page_name', $page_name],
    ['code', $pcode],
    /* 
         the arrays should have one of this two structure
         ["field", "value"], //using = operator as default
         ["field", "operator", "value"], 
     */
];
```

and than call `->where()` with this array as parameter, like:

```php
Page::where($where)->first();
```

So your code can become

```php
public function loadpage($name, $page_name, $pcode)
{
    $name = ['name', $name];
    $pageName = ['page_name', $page_name];
    $pageCode = [ 'code', $pcode ];
    $company = Company::where([$name])->first();
    if ($company === null) {
          return view('company.not_register', compact('name')); 
    }
    $page = Page::where([$name, $pageName])->first();
    if ($page === null) {
          return view('company.pages.erros.404', compact('name', page)); 
    }

    $pagecode = Page::where([$name, $pageName, $pageCode])->first();
    if ($pagecode === null) {
          return view('company.pages.erros.invalid_code', compact('company, name', page, pcode)); 
    }

    $personality = DB::table('personalities')->where([$name])->first();

     return view('company.pages.index', compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'page', pcode));
}
```